# Remove permission to push to develop or master without forking?

Tags: git, github

In my company we use [Git workflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow/), and have a lot of people working on our projects.

Sometimes we get some new people in, and they have some trouble understanding they may never ever touch `develop` or `master` themselves.

Without using the forking workflow, is there anyway to disallow developers to commit to `develop` / `master` directly, but only on features?

I use Github if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disallow direct commits to any particular branch, edit the hook file pre-commit in the hooks directory.

Read [the docs](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) on the topic to drill down to your specific case.

For preventing commits to `master`, add the following code to be run first:

```
branch=`git symbolic-ref HEAD`
if [ "$branch" = "refs/heads/master" ]; then
    echo "Direct commits to the branch master are not allowed"
    exit 1
fi
```

[Reference](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow/issues/330)